# Custom Shipping Method as fallback

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, programmatically

I've created a **shipping method** in

> magento2

. It checks if there is any oversize product in cart and if the package weight is more than 31.5 kg.

**How can I set this shipping method as default if there is no other method available in checkout?**

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\PickUpPackage\Model\Carrier;

    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

    class PickUpPackage extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_code = 'pickuppackage';

        protected $_logger;
        /**
         * @var bool
         */
        protected $_isFixed = true;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
         */
        protected $_rateResultFactory;


        /**
         * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
         */
        protected $_rateMethodFactory;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
         * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
         * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
         * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
            \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
            \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
            \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
            $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
            $this->_logger = $logger;
            parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
        }

        /**
         * @param RateRequest $request
         * @return \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result|bool
         */
        public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
        {   
            $oversizeItemIncluded = false;
            if ($request->getAllItems()) {
                foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    if ($item->getProduct()->getOversize()) {
                        $oversizeItemIncluded = true;
                    }
                    if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                            if ($child->getProduct()->getOversize()) {
                                $oversizeItemIncluded = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
            $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

            if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') || ($request->getPackageWeight() < 31.5 && !$oversizeItemIncluded && count($result->getAllRates()) >= 1)) {
                return false;
            }


            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);
            $result->append($method);


            return $result;
        }

        /**
         * @return array
         */
        public function getAllowedMethods()
        {

            return [$this->_code=> $this->getConfigData('name')];
        }
    }
```